# How to create a background that auto adjusts in height

Tags: html, css, typescript, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a background that auto adjusts in height as I add content.
If there is no content, the background should cover the entire screen, 100vh. As I add content the background should adjust in height until it reaches its minimum height of 100px. I have included an image to show demo what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

I have tried using min/max/100%/auto height properties and cant seem to find a solution.

I am using vue 3, typescript and css in my project.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Look into using flexbox as that will be able to give you an solution

Comment: @RichardHpa I thought I could achieve that by setting a min and max height. Your solution is exactly what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using flexbox would give you exactly what you are asking for. In a nut shell what is happening is the parent container is using display flex which causes the children use flexbox properties. The .background div then has `flex-grow : 1` which pretty much says grow as much as you can to fill the container. That means it will grow to fill the left over space of the parent depending on how much text there is.

```css
            .flex-container {
                display: flex;
                height: 100vh;
                flex-direction: column;
            }
            .background {
                background-color: blue;
                flex-grow: 1;
            }
```

```html
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="background">
                <h1>my background div</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer
                finibus, odio vel scelerisque convallis, leo odio scelerisque urna, ut
                scelerisque elit urna id quam. Etiam tempus pretium erat a semper.
                Mauris consequat scelerisque ante id volutpat. Suspendisse convallis,
                ipsum ut vehicula vehicula, lorem mauris porttitor enim, sollicitudin
                ultrices lectus sem et ipsum. Morbi feugiat, lorem at viverra mattis,
                neque enim vehicula turpis, blandit luctus eros eros ut arcu. Praesent
                facilisis pharetra consectetur. Maecenas sagittis commodo felis, vitae
                tristique risus. Phasellus fermentum varius turpis vel rhoncus. Nullam
                aliquet nec risus non interdum. Sed nec magna pellentesque, facilisis
                felis ac, cursus leo. Fusce et tortor magna. Fusce odio eros, varius non
                placerat mattis, ullamcorper sed purus.
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your text container to hide the background underneath.

```css
.container {
   border: solid 1px grey;
   background-color: red;
   position: relative;
   height: 250px;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    <p>Here is some text <br /> on multiple <br /> lines.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```